# How to substitute values in XML using java

Tags: java, xml

Lets assume I have an XML as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <salary>$substitute_me</salary>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <salary>$substitute_me_2</salary>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

In the above XML, I want to substitute values of `$substitute_me` and `$substitute_me_2` (either from user input or from a conf file).

Answer (score 0):

There's numerous ways, but since you don't call for anything more than a replace, I'd say use the built in replace methods of the `String` class:

```
//XML read to xmlstring
String xmlstring = new String(encoded, encoding);
String resultstring = xmlstring.replace("string_to_replace","new_string");
// XML saved with replacement
```